# Count specific pattern in seqID python

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

I actually have a huge multifasta seq file such:

```
>Seq_1_0035_0035
ATTGGAT
>Seq_2_0042_0035
ATTGAGGA
>EOGWX56TR_0035_0042 (busco)
ATGGAGAT
>EOGWX56TR_0042_0042 (busco)
ATGGATGG
>Seq6_035_0042
ATGGGAATAG
>EOG55FTG_0035_0042 (busco)
AATGGATA
>EOG5GFFTA_0042_0042 (busco)
ATGGAGATA
>Seq56_0035_0042
ATGGAGATAT
>EOGATTT_0035_0042  (busco)
AAATGAGATA
>EOGATTT_0042_0042  (busco)
ATGGAAT
>EOGATTA_0042_0042  (busco)
ATAGGAGAT
```

and I actually want to count how many Busco gene I have in my file (they all begins with the name `>EOG`) To do so I have a script such:

```
count=1
for record in SeqIO.parse("concatenate_with_busco_names_0035_0042_aa.fa", "fasta"):
    count+=1
print(count)

set_of_labels = set()

with open("concatenate_with_busco_names_0035_0042_aa.fa") as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>EOG'):
      label = line[4:].split('_')[0]
      set_of_labels.add(label)

print("Total number of Busco genes: " + str(len(set_of_labels)))
```

But what I also would like is to know how many gene I have between each corresponding comportiments. I explain it better;

As you can see there are two number in each seqID `such _number_number`
These number are particular and the first `_number` correspond to the species to which the sequence belongs and the second `_number` its a particular number.
Anyway I would like if it is possible to count as I did how many different Busco gene I get for seq with the first number `_0035` and `_0042`
AND also 
how many for seq ID:

```
_0035_0042
_0035_0042
_0042_0042
_0042_0035
```

In the above exemple it would be:

```
Total busco: 5 (I count only once if the >busco is present even if _number are different)
Total busco for the specie _0035 (_0035_0042 and _0035_0035) : 3
Total busco for the specie _0042 (_0042_0042 and _0042_0035) : 4
Total busco for the specific specie  _0035_0042 : 3
Total busco for the specific specie  _0042_0035 : 0
Total busco for the specific specie  _0042_0042 : 4
Total busco for the specific specie  _0035_0035 : 0
```

Hi hope it is clear, in fact the first part (`total busco:`) is already done by my script, I only have to count the 7 other manners.

here is the real data [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zqloRWvMYAFp8ymBCckioHCsUHnaz7dw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What about using two dictionaries which store the number of matches? One which has the key `_number_number` and one for `_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple counters to get individual counts for *species* and *specific species* in addition to the *busco* counter, e.g.:

```
import collections

busco = collections.defaultdict(int)  # busco counter
species = collections.defaultdict(int)  # species counter
specific_species = collections.defaultdict(int)  # specific species counter

with open("concatenate_with_busco_names_0035_0042_aa.fa", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:4] == ">EOG":
            entry = line.split()[0][4:].split('_')
            busco[entry[0]] += 1
            species[entry[1]] += 1
            specific_species[entry[1] + "_" + entry[2]] += 1

print("Total busco: {}".format(len(busco)))
for specie, total in species.items():
    print("Total busco for the specie {}: {}".format(specie, total))
for specie, total in specific_species.items():
    print("Total busco for the specific specie {}: {}".format(specie, total))
```

Which should yield:

```
Total busco: 5
Total busco for the specie 0035: 3
Total busco for the specie 0042: 4
Total busco for the specific specie 0035_0042: 3
Total busco for the specific specie 0042_0042: 4
```

Non-listed (specific) species won't show up but if you really want to print them out you can combine them from the `species` counter and print their values (default is `0`):

```
import itertools

print("Total busco: {}".format(len(busco)))
for specie, total in species.items():
    print("Total busco for the specie {}: {}".format(specie, total))
for specie in itertools.product(species, species):
    s = "_".join(specie)
    print("Total busco for the specific specie {}: {}".format(s, specific_species[s]))
```

Which yields:

```
Total busco: 5
Total busco for the specie 0035: 3
Total busco for the specie 0042: 4
Total busco for the specific specie 0035_0035: 0
Total busco for the specific specie 0035_0042: 3
Total busco for the specific specie 0042_0035: 0
Total busco for the specific specie 0042_0042: 4
```

**UPDATE**: If you're after unique counts per *busco* then you need to inverse the count to index on *specie* / *specific specie* and collect *busco* values in a `set` as their value. Then all you need is to get the length of each set, something like:

```
import collections
import itertools

busco = set()
species = collections.defaultdict(set)
specific_species = collections.defaultdict(set)

with open("concatenate_with_busco_names_0035_0042_aa.fa", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:4] == ">EOG":
            entry = line.split()[0][4:].split('_')
            busco.add(entry[0])
            species[entry[1]].add(entry[0])
            specific_species[entry[1] + "_" + entry[2]].add(entry[0])

print("Total busco: {}".format(len(busco)))
for specie, buscos in species.items():
    print("Total busco for the specie {}: {}".format(specie, len(buscos)))
for specie in itertools.product(species, species):
    s = "_".join(specie)
    print("Total busco for the specific specie {}: {}".format(s, len(specific_species[s])))
```

Which for your full data prints:

```
Total busco: 421
Total busco for the specie 0035: 402
Total busco for the specie 0042: 397
Total busco for the specific specie 0035_0035: 392
Total busco for the specific specie 0035_0042: 262
Total busco for the specific specie 0042_0035: 305
Total busco for the specific specie 0042_0042: 383
```

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your help :) But it seems something is going wrong because I get to much number and I have only 422 >EOGsomething different values in my data and I actually get something like 854 and when I replace if line[:4] == ">EOG" by if line[:4] == ">EOG090X03YJ": to see if the code works I get 0 and I should get number tot busco= 1, 0042_0042 = 1; 0042_0035 =0; 0035_0042 = 0 and _0035_0035 =0. I added my real data if you want to check :)

Comment: You didn't state (or at least it wasn't clear to me) that you want the other two counters to be dependent on their parents as well, i.e. count `species/specific_specie` only for unique `busco` entries. With the code above, if there are two `>EOG01_02_03` entries only one `busco` will be counted (`01`) but the species (`02`) and the specific species (`02_03`) will be increased by one on each encounter resulting in a count of `2`.

Comment: Yep for the total it is ok, the number is right (only count one occurence of Busco within all species and specific species). But for total of the specie `_0035` for exemple if there are something like `>EOG01_02_03` and `>EOG01_02_04` I just want to count one busco). Then to be more specific I want to count within each situations then here it will be: `_02_03 =1` busco and `_02_04 =1` busco. Maybe you can take a look at the real data I put in my first post with a like to better understand ?

Comment: I took a look at the data and I'm still not clear on what you're attempting to do - the `busco` count is unique due to its keys being stored in a `dict` (but you can get a count of all encountered `busco` entries with `sum(busco.values())`) but the subsequent numbers are treated separately. Do you want them counted **only** on unique `busco` entries (e.g. if there are two entries as: `>EOG01_02_03` and `>EOG01_02_04` it should count one _busco_ (`01`), one _specie_ (`02`) and two _specific species_ (`02_03` and `02_04`))?

Comment: Yes in your exemple there 3 level of counting, first only one busco entries (`all busco`), second depending on the specie (`first _number`) but if there is `EOG01_02_03` and `EOG01_02_04` you can only one busco entrie and `third`: you count all different busco entries :) Then because there are 4 specific species, it makes 6 defferent values to count.

Comment: @Benjamin - Ok, I think I finally understood what you're after. Check the update above.

Comment: Thank you it was exactly wat I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

That is trivial to do with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from Python standard library:

```
from collections import Counter
from io import StringIO

label_counter = Counter()
specy_counter = Counter()
specific_specy_counter = Counter()

# replace this with an open() on your real file 
finput = StringIO(""">Seq_1_0035_0035
ATTGGAT
>Seq_2_0042_0035
ATTGAGGA
>EOGWX56TR_0035_0042 (busco)
ATGGAGAT
>EOGWX56TR_0042_0042 (busco)
ATGGATGG
>Seq6_035_0042
ATGGGAATAG
>EOG55FTG_0035_0042 (busco)
AATGGATA
>EOG5GFFTA_0042_0042 (busco)
ATGGAGATA
>Seq56_0035_0042
ATGGAGATAT
>EOGATTT_0035_0042  (busco)
AAATGAGATA
>EOGATTT_0042_0042  (busco)
ATGGAAT
>EOGATTA_0042_0042  (busco)
ATAGGAGAT""")



for line in finput:
    try:
        if line.startswith('>EOG'):
            label, specy, specific = line[4:].replace(" (busco)", "").strip().split('_')
            label_counter[label] += 1
            specy_counter[specy] += 1
            specific_specy_counter[(specy, specific)] += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid line:", line)


print("Total busco:", len(label_counter))
for specy, count in specy_counter.items():
    print("Total busco for the specie {} : {}".format(specy, count))
for (specy, specific), count in specific_specy_counter.items():
    print("Total busco for the specific specy {}_{} : {}".format(specy, specific, count))
```

Note that species or specifics with 0 values won't show up.